# Knockout: provide custom data-attribute of $element to click event handler

Tags: html, knockout.js, attributes

Is it possible to access any of the `data-*` attributes on the object that [$element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) refers to?

In a binding for the click event, i.e.

```
data-bind="click: function() { myfunction(arg);})"
```

I was able to use `$element.id` for arg, but I would have prefered `$element.data-id`, because it's much more meaningful to store my information (a database id) in one of the `data-*` attributes instead of the `id` attribute. Unfortunately, `$element.data-id` gives me an error (using knockout 2.2.0): "id is not defined" (something seems to choke on the dash).

Comment: I don't see the html5 connection

Comment: data-attributes are only available from html 5 onwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery to get the attribute off the element:

```
$($element).attr('data-id');
```

Comment: Others might find this useful for passing in the element as a parameter: `data-bind="click: function() { myfunction.bind($data, $element) })"`